# UPDATE column with the first not empty occurrence from another table that matching id

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update

I would like to update names in a very large table with the first not empty name value from another table, but the other table stores multiple language names and couldn't figure out a working query for this.

Table a looks like this:

```
id | name 
 1 | test name
 2 | test name 2
```

Table b looks like this:

```
id | table_a_id | name                   | lang_id
 1 | 1          | new name               |  1
 2 | 1          |                        |  2
 3 | 1          | new name in other lang |  3
 4 | 2          |                        |  1
 5 | 2          | other new name         |  2
 6 | 2          |                        |  3
```

And the result which I would like to get:

table a

```
id | name
 1 | new name
 2 | other new name
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it says? The best answer depends on if you can use features of MySQL 8.0 or not.

Comment: What is the exact role of `lang_id` in your logic?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward is a solution with a subselect and limit 1:

```
update tablea a 
   set a.name = (SELECT name FROM
                 tableb b1 
                  where name is not null 
                    and b1.tablea_id = a.id 
               order by language_id
                limit 1);
```

It won't be the fastest, as Bill Kawrin says...